# How to setup a push messaging service in my web app in Java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I want to create a push messaging service in my web app using Java.
Any suggestions where should i start?

thanks,
Kazi

Comment: do you mean pushing message from server to browser-client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Atmosphere](http://techdiary.bitourea.com/2011/11/atmosphere-with-jquery-tutorial-to.html) framework is good for push notifications.

[Source details](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMS for this, provided by Java, you can find an example at http://oreilly.com/catalog/javmesser/chapter/ch02.html.

 There are few other open source APIs also available, but it depends upon your requirement.

Comment: is JMS used to create a chat apllication or can we integrate it in the web app?

Comment: JMS is mainly used to create chat applications, but that is not its only use. That is why I said you have to choose the technology based upon your requirement.

Comment: Can i use it in a web app?

Comment: yes, you can. There are ways to do that. you might need to research a bit.